# How to use distinct with pipeline in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

i have data like this

```
{ "_id": "1234gbrghr",
  "Device" : "samsung",
  "UserId" : "12654",
  "Month" : "july"
},

{ "_id": "1278gbrghr",
  "Device" : "nokia",
  "UserId" : "87654",
  "Month" : "july"
},

{ "_id": "1234gbrghr",
  "Device" : "samsung",
  "UserId" : "12654",
  "Month" : "july"
}
```

I need to get the no of distinct user for a particular device in the month of july . for example " If a user(UserId) used samsung device twice or more in the month of july then it will count it as one for samsung .

For this i used this query to get the total no of users in the the month of july . but i need to get the distinct no of users

```
pipeline1 = [

            {'$match':{'Month':'july'}},
            {'$group':{'_id' : '$Device', 'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }}}
          ]
    data = db.command('aggregate', 'collection', pipeline=pipeline1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to group on device **and** user instead first. You can do that with the following pipeline operator:

```
{'$group':{'_id' : { d: '$Device', u: '$UserId' } } }
```

And then secondly you need to count the number of devices per user (like you already had, but slighty modified:

```
{ '$group': { '_id' : '$_id.d', 'count': { '$sum' : 1 } } }
```

With the following dataset:

```
{ "_id" : "1234gbrghr", "Device" : "samsung", "UserId" : "12654", "Month" : "july" }
{ "_id" : "1278gbrghr", "Device" : "nokia", "UserId" : "87654", "Month" : "july" }
{ "_id" : "1239gbrghr", "Device" : "samsung", "UserId" : "12654", "Month" : "july" }
{ "_id" : "1238gbrghr", "Device" : "samsung", "UserId" : "12653", "Month" : "july" }
```

And the following aggregate command:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { '$match' : {'Month' : 'july' } },
    { '$group' : {
        '_id' : { d: '$Device', u: '$UserId' },
        'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
    } }, 
    { '$group': {
        '_id' : '$_id.d',
        'count': { '$sum' : 1 }
    } }
] );
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "nokia",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "samsung",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```